# Continuity with the Riemann-Stieltjes integral

Tags: integration, analysis, continuity, alternative-proof, bounded-variation

Given $c\in (a,b),$ define $\alpha :[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ by: $$\alpha(x) =
\begin{cases}
-1,  & \alpha \le x\le c \\[2ex]
1, & c<x\le b
\end{cases}$$ Prove that if $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ satisfies $$\lim_{x\to c^+}f(x)=f(c),$$
then $f\in R(\alpha)$ on $[a,b].$ ($R(\alpha)$ means Riemann-Stieltjes integration respect to $\alpha$ function)

Proof:

We have the continuity of $f$ because of this $\lim_{x\to c^+}f(x)=f(c),$ (I guess..)

So we just need $\alpha $ to be of Bounded Variation, $\alpha\in BV([a,b]).$ (If we have this, then the proof ends)

As $\alpha$ in defined in a compact set, we just need to check that $\alpha $ is continuous to then conclude that $\alpha$ is bounded, and therefore $\alpha\in BV([a,b]).$

Is my idea a good idea to proof the theorem?

Any kind of suggest/help is welcome.

Comment: the statement $\lim_{x\to c^+}f(x)=f(c)$ says that $f$ is continuous **by the right** at $x=c$, but not that $f$ is continuous at $x=c$.

Comment: @Masacroso Oh , then what can I do to have the continuity of $f?$

Comment: I think that $f$ is not necessarily continuous but because the above holds for all $c\in(a,b)$ probably (Im not sure) you can show that every discontinuity of $f$, if exists, is a jump discontinuity.

Comment: @RRL Could you give the idea for the proof? please? (this problem might come in my exam, and my exam is tomorrow , I ask for your help bc I know you domain all the Riemann-Stlsj knowledge :)